# C# CodeFirst Enum EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

I'm trying to use codefirstdatabase in my applicantion, but I'm nothing having success in mapping the enum in my application.
I'm receiving that error when I try to use it.
(6,10) : error 3032: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 6:Condition member 'BasicAccount.AccountType' with a condition other than 'IsNull=False' is mapped. Either remove the condition on BasicAccount.AccountType or remove it from the mapping.

```
public class PersonalDate
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BaseAccount> BaseAccounts{ get; set; }
   
    public PersonalDate()
    { }
```

}

```
public class BasicAccount

{
    public int id { get; set; }
     public AccountType AccountType { get; set; }
     public PersonalDate PersonalDate { get; set }
     
    public BasicAccount()
    {
    }
```

}

```
public class CurrentAccount: BasicAccount
{

    public CurrentAccount() 
    {
        AccountType = AccountType.CurrentAccount;
    }

}

public class SavingAccount: BasicAccount
{

    public SavingAccount() 
    {
        AccountType = AccountType.SavingAccount;
    }

}
public class SalaryAccount: BasicAccount
{

    public SalaryAccount() 
    {
        AccountType = AccountType.SalaryAccount;
    }

}
public enum AccountType: int
{
    undefined= 0,
    SavingAccount= 1,
    CurrentAccount= 2,
    SalaryAccount= 3
}

public class BancoContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<DadoPessoa> DadosPessoas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ContaBase> ContaBases { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);


                 modelBuilder.Entity<BasicAccount>()
            .HasRequired<PersonalDate>(x => x.PersonalDate);
  modelBuilder.Entity<BasicAccount>()  
            .Map<BasicAccount>( x => x.Requires("AccountType").HasValue((int)AccountType.Undefined))
            .Map<SavingAccount>(x => .Requires("AccountType").HasValue((int)AccountType.SavingAccount))
            .Map<CurrentAccount>(x => x.Requires("AccountType").HasValue((int)AccountType.CurrentAccount))
            .Map<SalaryAccount>(x => x.Requires("AccountType").HasValue((int)AccountType.SalaryAccount));
```

}

Comment: Try adding `.IsRequired()` after `.HasValue(...)`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried, didn't worked it.

Comment: You're not telling the whole story here. You also have a TPT mapping, which means that `AccountType` can't be a property of your `BasicAccount` entity.

Comment: @GertArnold what should I do then? Sorry I'm new in programming and doing this basic application to improve my skills.

Comment: Doing the TPT mapping. So I will have to do a TPT mapping and the enum mapping?

Comment: Did that TPT, now still receiving enum error: Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: I missed the TPT part because it's not visible without scrolling. But as I said, `AccountType` can't be a property in your class when it's used as discriminator. That's all. This primitive types error is something entirely different, not in the scope of this question.